# How can I get the screen width and length in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-button

I want to display 9 buttons in the middle of the display, three on each row. In conclusion a big square that is composed from 9 little buttons displayed in the middle of the screen.
So I think I need to know the screen size to display buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need to use Tablelayout or Linerlayout for this.but if need to know screen size it get as following :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();  
int height = display.getHeight();
```

If you're not in an Activity you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE:

```
 WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```